# No CSS or images on 404 pages

Tags: css, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I got problem with 404 pages. They just don't show any images and looks like css files does not load.
Before asking i did investigate more and found possible fix for this one, but i am not sure, if its right or not.

```
<base href="/">
```

is enought to fix this problem, but is this right way to do it?

Here is website with 404 page, i did remove this tag at this moment from head.
https://www.xeovo.com/blahblahblah

Thanks.

Comment: This is very odd. After removing this tag from head, everything looks okay. But its probably temporary.

Comment: working for me [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/d849xm)

Comment: Yeah, i don't understand. Several hours ago it was not working without this tag in head.

Comment: Yup. You need the base tag but ideally you should use absolute URLs for stylesheets, css and other assets. Example of broken 404 page: https://www.xeovo.com/blah/blahblah